# Need to delete just one string from an array that might have duplicates

Tags: ios, arrays, ios7

I have an array that stores strings of items that are being bought. They might buy two of the same thing. When I used the if statement below it removes all instances of that string and I need it to just remove one. Please help.

```
Singleton *shared = [Singleton sharedManager];
if ([shared.array2 containsObject:string2]) {
        [shared.array2 removeObject:string2];
    }
```

Comment: is it possible that the array holds two NSString that are different instances but contain the same string? In this case comparison should be made on the string content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSUInteger index = [shared.array2 indexOfObject:string2];
if (index != NSNotFound) {
   [shared.array2 removeObjectAtIndex: index];
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Waiting until it lets me accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray has a method called `indexOfObject` that will return either the lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to anObject or `NSNotFound` if no such object is found. Just get index and call `removeObjectAtIndex` this will remove first found matching object.

Answer (score -1):

It is Simple just covert *NSArray* to *NSSet*. *NSSet* not allowed to store duplicate objects.

it is automatically delete duplicate objects. below code we are going to use fix this issue.

```
NSSet * set = [NSSet setWithArray:NSArray(instance here)];
```